# Torx wrenches T15 and T20

Tags: tools

Is there anything between a T15 and a T20 torx that I can use.  I have tried three sets and none of them worked.  I have even tried using allen wrenches both metric and sae.  Please help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4):

No. There's no bit between T15 and T20.

My suggestion back to you is, maybe it's not a Torx bit you need. It might be something other than a Torx (there are a plethora of different bits). Secondarily, you may have stripped the head out. (Note: A picture in your question of the screw you are trying to remove would have been helpful here.)

Comment: Not only that but there are a bunch of different type of bits.

Comment: I found out that a square #2 bit is the answer. Thank you

Comment: Yay robertson !  A Canadian invention,eh ?